# Link variables in GNU Bash (4.4.20)

Tags: bash, environment-variables

In GNU Bash (5.0.17) I would like to link two (or more) variables i.e., when variable #1 changes value, variable #2 should automatically have its value set to the value of variable #1 and vice versa.

I've tried the following (all from Bash command line), and it works, but only when you insert a space after the variable name during assignment.
However this not good enough for me, I'd prefer `myvar1=test` i.e. without space, but I fear this is not possible...?

```
$ bash --version
```

> ```
> GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release
> ```

```
$ myvar1() {
    myvar1=$(echo "$@" | cut -d'=' -f2-)
    myvar2="$myvar1"
    }
$ myvar2() {
    myvar1=$(echo "$@" | cut -d'=' -f2-)
    myvar2="$myvar1"
    }
$ echo "$myvar1:$myvar2:" # Unset at this point
```

> ```
> ::
> ```

```
$ myvar1 =abc
$ echo "$myvar1:$myvar2:"
```

> ```
> abc:abc:
> ```

```
$ myvar2 =def
$ echo "$myvar1:$myvar2:"
```

> ```
> def:def:
> ```

The reason for this is to keep legacy variables still being used but also support new variables, used elsewhere, where these variable pairs should go hand in hand value-wise.

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.
Also please update your question and explain what is the end goal,

Comment: I think the closest you could get to this would be by pre-processing the script file and replacing all occurrences of the second variable with the name of the first one. Which would be very challenging and time-consuming to pull off correctly.

Comment: `VAR1 =test` calls the *function* `VAR1` with one argument, `=test`. `VAR1=test` sets the *variable* `$VAR1` to `test`.

Comment: @Jetchisel Thank you for your input - I have updated my post to make things clearer. shellcheck.net gave no issues (part of lack of shebang)

Comment: @Shawn Yes, that is correctly understood. However I am looking for a way to chain one variable to another, triggered by assignment as per `VAR1=test`...

Comment: If you're improving your naming convention, it's unfortunate that you aren't switching to lowercase names as POSIX suggests for application-defined variables (the all-caps namespace is used for names meaningful to the shell itself and POSIX-defined tools; lowercase names are reserved for application use).

Comment: (See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind in reading it that environment variables and regular shell variables share a single namespace -- as changing a shell variable will update any like-named environment variable -- so the same conventions apply to both)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, I know, the caps in my example isn't great. I'll change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your bash is recent enough you could simply make `VAR2` a *nameref* of `VAR1`:

```
$ declare -n VAR2=VAR1
$ VAR1=foo
$ echo $VAR2
foo
```

Note that the association is symmetrical:

```
$ VAR2=bar
$ echo $VAR1
bar
```

(but they are not equivalent, `VAR2` is a nameref, `VAR1` is not; for instance, to unset `VAR1` you just `unset VAR1`, while to really unset `VAR2` you need the `-n` option of `unset`, else, with `unset VAR2`,  you unset `VAR1`).

Comment: Brilliant. Just what I was looking for.